# Slider is not working in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django

i want to make create and manage slider in django. i can create in admin page but when i will show image in home page its not show anything.

this is my models.py

```
class Static(models.Model):
title           = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description     = models.TextField()
images1         = models.ImageField(upload_to="slider")
images2         = models.ImageField(upload_to="slider")

def __str__(self):
    return self.title;
```

view.py

```
def slider(request):
sliders = Static.objects.all()
return render(request, 'kerajinan/home.html', {
'sliders' : sliders,
})
```

home.html

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
                        {% for i in image %}
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <h2>{{i.title}}</h2>
                                    <p>{{i.description}}</p>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default get">Get it now</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <img src="{{ i.images1.url }}" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" />
                                    <img src="{{ i.images2.url }}" class="pricing" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}

                        {{slider|pprint}}

                    </div>
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
MEDIA_URL  = '/static/images/'
```

Urls.py:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^home/$', 'kerajinan.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^static/images/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
)
```

i already check data with this

```
python manage.py shell
>>>from kerajinan.models import Static
>>>sliders = Static.objects.all()
>>>sliders
```

and result is record data. 
can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write custom method to get the URL for an image. You can access an image URL in template directly:

```
{{ i.images1.url }}
```

Comment: first time i use {{ i.images1.url }} but its not working, So i custom method to get URL.